# Listview demand focus when added to a layout

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I want to add a ListView to a LinearLayout. But when the app start it demand focus and open the keyboard. I don't want it to do that.

I have tried both XML and Java code:

```
contentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.contentView);
contentList = new ListView(this);
contentList.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
contentLayout.addView(contentList);
```

XML

```
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/listView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I ask the question a little wrong.

But I find out that since I have an input field, the system always want to focus in an input. So I set in the Android Manifest that windowSoftInputMode to stateHidden.

Know the keyboard doesn't open automically when the activity start.